# How to check whether a php datetime variable is within range

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've checked the PHP manuals, and also googled prior to asking this question, but am still confused about how to do this correctly -  How can I check whether my datetime variable's time part is greater than a given time?

Suppose I have a variable `$time` like the following:

```
$mdata['entry_date_time'] = $this->input->post('entry_date_time');
$time = $mdata['entry_date_time']->format('H:i:s');
```

What I want to do is something like this:

```
if($time > 12:00:00)
{
    //do something
}
```

My questions, based on the second code snippet, are:

1. Is my syntax correct?
2. If not, then what is the correct syntax?
3. Is there any better approach to what I'm trying to do, other than my approach? If so, then what is it?

Comment: what is the original value of `entry_date_time` ? this is coming from a form right?

Comment: @Ghost, yes, it's coming from a form. Assume that it's a datetime value of the current system time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the format of the input, you could use datetime in this case:

```
$date_input = $this->input->post('entry_date_time');
$date = new DateTime($date_input);
if($date->format('H') > 12) {
    // do what you have to do
}
```

If you have a format that cannot be used directly on the constructor, you might need to use `createFromFormat`:

To answer fully:

1. No, its not correct since most likely your post values are strings and therefore having `->` an arrow operator doesn't make sense since its not an object.
2. and 3. The answer above.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much Ghost for such an excellent answer. I was in desperate need of this help. I was so confused and lost about the syntax.